# Spring-Data-Rest: countBy*** method/Query not working

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am learning the Spring-Data-Rest and trying to add the **countBy***** functionality in my Customer Repository. However, when I try to make the api call:
`//<app>/customers/search/countByFirstnameUsingQuery?firstname=Dave`, or
`//<app>/customers/search/countByFirstname?firstname=Dave` I get **500 Internal Server Error**.

Below is how my repository looks like

---

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{


Customer findByEmailAddress(@Param("emailAddress") EmailAddress emailAddress);

@Query("select c from Customer c where c.firstname = :firstname")
Customer findByFirstNameUsingQuery(@Param("firstname") String firstname);

public long countByFirstname(@Param("firstname") String firstname);

@Query("select count(c) from Customer c where c.firstname = :firstname") 
Long countByFirstnameUsingQuery(@Param("firstname") String firstname);

 }
```

---

Below is my Customer class

```
@Entity
public class Customer extends AbstractEntity {

private String firstname, lastname;

@Column(unique = true)
private EmailAddress emailAddress;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
```

---

There is no exception coming on the server. Below is all what comes to the server logs
However, below is what comes to the logs.

```
2014-05-08 13:02:05,551 DEBUG rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping: 219 - Looking up handler method for path /customers/search/countByFirstname  
2014-05-08 13:02:05,567 DEBUG rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping: 226 - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?>>  
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
```

---

Please let me know if any further details required.

Any input on the above shall be much appreciated.

---

When I access, I gets "500 Internal Server Error".
To me it looks that spring data rest is not supporting exposing count as rest api.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the server?

Comment: There is no error coming on the server. It looks the exception is getting eaten up.

Comment: Without any exception it is hard to tell what is going on, but my guess is that the `RepositorySearchController` is not generating a handler method for count. Can you try and implement it manually calling the Repository methods, on order to test them?

Comment: It works when I create my controller/ service layer and manually call the repository method. Any one, who knows that if this is supported by spring data rest.

Comment: Query resource methods are supported. Look at the sample https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book. Probably the url at which you are trying to call the method is not the one generated by default.

Comment: how did you solve it?